# How can I join this 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is the `SP_ARCHIVE` table
[image]

This is the `Account` table
[image]

This is the `Proponent` table
[image]

What the query should output is `sp_archive.SP_ID`, `sp_archive.SP_Title`, `sp_archive.SP_Type`, `Account.Account_FirstName`, `Account.MiddleName`, and `Account.LastName`.

The `name` should be different column

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
select  sp_archive.SP_ID, sp_archive.SP_Title, sp_archive.SP_Type, 
Account.Account_FirstName, Account.MiddleName, Account.LastName from 
SP_ARCHIVE join Proponent using (SP_ID) join Account using 
(Account_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query for your problem:

```
$this->db->select('sp_archive.SP_ID, sp_archive.SP_Title, sp_archive.SP_Type, Account.Account_FirstName, Account.MiddleName, Account.LastName');
$this->db->from('Proponent');
$this->db->join('sp_archive', 'sp_archive.SP_ID=Proponent.SP_ID ', 'left');
$this->db->join('Account', 'Account.Account_ID = Proponent.Account_ID', 'left');

$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
exit;
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just left join **Account** and **SP_ARCHIVE** with **Proponent**

```
SELECT `sp_archive`.`SP_ID`, 
       `sp_archive`.`SP_Title`, 
       `sp_archive`.`SP_Type`, 
       `Account`.`Account_FirstName`, 
       `Account`.`MiddleName`, 
       `Account`.`LastName` 
FROM `Proponent` 
LEFT JOIN `Account` 
       ON `Account`.`Account_ID` = `Proponent`.`Account_ID` 
LEFT JOIN `SP_ARCHIVE` 
       ON `SP_ARCHIVE`.`SP_ID` = `Proponent`.`SP_ID`
```

Comment: what if the proponent can have multiple values? What i mean is for every SP_ARCHIVE can have multiple Proponent

Answer (score 0):

Look up CI query builder https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Create a model and then make a function to place your query in:

```
$select = 'av.SP_ID, sp_archive.SP_Title, av.SP_Type, a.Account_FirstName, a.MiddleName,a.LastName';

$results = $this->db->select($select)
//if you want it to be an inner join remove 3rd param from join
->join('sp_archive av', 'av.SP_ID=p.SP_ID ', 'left');
->join('Account a', 'a.Account_ID = p.Account_ID', 'left')
//aliase tabel names
->get('Proponent p')->result();

return $results;
```